# My query is not returning what I expect, how can I restructure it?

Tags: mysql

Apologies for how vague the question is, but here's what I'm looking at. I need to form a query for the following:

Find the number of episodes watched by each customer, sorted by customer last name.

I have a table for "watched" that has FK to episode, customer, show, and date watched. I have a customer table. I was doing this as my initial attempt...

```
SELECT c.lname, count(w.episodeID) 
FROM customer c, watched w, episode e, shows s 
WHERE c.custID = w.custID 
ORDER BY c.lname ASC
```

...with the intention of saying ok, between a row of "watched" where it is related to the customer through its FK, return the last name and the number of episodes in that watched row.

It just returns one customer last name rather than a list, and a very, very large number for the count. How can I go about listing the customers with their respective count?

Please, if I am leaving out helpful information, kindly let me know what else to add and I will provide more info.

Comment: You implicitly JOIN **four** tables but provide relationship only for **two** of them.  So you get a partial Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out GROUP-BY. WS3 has great docs. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp